# how do I run cpp files on a raspberry pi3?

Tags: pi-3

how do I run cpp files on a raspberry pi3?
I tried using bluefish and chrome, 
but it didn't work, please someone
tell me how to do it.

Comment: cpp are typically C++ source files.  You need to compile, link, then you can run the resulting program.  Perhaps look at raspberrypi.org for help.  General programming questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: `I tried using bluefish and chrome` ... this does not describe what you did ........ `it didn't work` does not describe what the result was .... if you want a useful answer, then you have to describe in some detail what you tried and what the results were

Comment: You should come up with an **example** (linked, of course) of such a cpp file you encountered so we can tell you where you took the wrong turn.

Answer (score 1):

CPP are C++ files, you need to compile the source using g++.

`g++ -o outputFilename inputFilename.cpp`

Using *BlueFish Editor* you can create / edit CPP files, You cannot use *Google Chrome* for CPP output.